# Synology NAS VPN connection woes from iOS devices

Tags: vpn, nas, ios, synology, synology-diskstation

I’m trying to set up VPN on my home Synology NAS DS918+ so that I can use it while I’m traveling. I set it up for L2TP/IPSec:

[image]

As such:

[image]

To get an IP address of my home (I don’t have a static IP) I’m using Synology’s DDNS:

[image]

I also have Let’s Encrypt’s SSL certificate set up for my NAS:

[image]

I’m using the following settings on my iPhone (and also on my iPad) running iOS 14.8.1:

[image]

The VPN connects just fine and I can use it. (My IP changes to the one at home.) But the problem is that after a while (maybe from half an hour to an hour, or sometimes longer) when I turn on my iOS device (both iPhone and iPad) show this message:

> VPN Connection
>
> You were disconnected because the PPP server is not responding. Try
> reconnecting.

And when I go to settings in iOS, the VPN check box is off. So I have to turn it back on to re-connect.

This is very annoying, as what is the point of a VPN if it disconnects by itself.

I checked the logs on the NAS, and it had a bunch of these:

[image]

I also tried playing with settings for the VPN on the NAS. Like unchecking “Run in kernel mode” and specifying “Use manual DNS” to 1.1.1.1 but it doesn’t change anything and it still disconnects after a while.

Any idea what’s going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like a timeout happening. Could you run a continuous ping from your phone to your VPN and confirm that it still disconnects?

Comment: @mashuptwice how do I do that?

Comment: I was thinking about the same. Is there a power saving timeout for the NAS?